# XSL parsing using java

Tags: java, xslt

```
<xsl:template match="book">
    <html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            hr{height:1px;border:0;color: #ed1b2d;background-color: #ed1b2d;}
        </style>
    </head>
        <body><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="786" align="center"><tr><td><xsl:apply-templates/></td></tr></table></body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="booktable">
    <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2"><xsl:apply-templates/></table>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="bookrow">
    <tr><xsl:apply-templates/></tr>
</xsl:template>
```

--> Here i need to add ID attribute in match because it has CONTENT in it...is it possible in java

Comment: This isn't a well-defined and meaningful question. Please, edit the question and add: 1. A sample (small) source XML document. 2. A sample (complete and small) XSLT transformation. 3. The exact wanted result. 4. The result you get fro your transformation. 5. Description of all the requirements the transformation must implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XSL is XML so any XML parser api can be used. Search google for JAXP and DOM.

Comment: @HarishSaran - read this tutorial http://dcm.uhcl.edu/yue/courses/xml/notes/xmlparser/IntroDOM.asp

Comment: <xsl:template match="book">
  <html>
        <head>
         <style type="text/css">
    hr{height:1px;border:0;color: #ed1b2d;background-color: #ed1b2d;}
   </style>
        </head>
   <body><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="786" align="center"><tr><td><xsl:apply-templates/></td></tr></table></body>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="booktable">
  <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2"><xsl:apply-templates/></table>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="bookrow">
  <tr><xsl:apply-templates/></tr>
 </xsl:template>

Answer (score 1):

http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_1_1-Introduction.html#Introduction